# Kubuntu: GIMP denies installation, unmet dependencies

Tags: software-installation, gimp, atom-editor

```
root@myself:/home/myself# apt-get install gimp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 atom : Depends: git
        Depends: gvfs-bin
 gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.8.16) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgimp2.0 (<= 2.8.16-z) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: gimp-data (>= 2.8.16) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: gimp-data (<= 2.8.16-z) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: python-gtk2 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libbabl-0.1-0 (>= 0.1.10) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgegl-0.3-0 (>= 0.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libpoppler-glib8 (>= 0.18.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@myself:/home/myself#
```

I tried installing it through Discover (Kubuntu Software Center), but it claims that I need to get rid off atom in order to install GIMP. I need both. I haven't tried `apt-get -f install` as it's most likely going to delete atom. Is there a way to have both on my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Comment: Nope. Leaves me with exactly same error. Word by word.

Comment: @J.Doe i edit my answer

Comment: Well, it worked, now you could explain me why regular way didn't work, how Kubuntu doesn't have Ubuntu's GIMP. And what was special about your way to didn't mess it all up.

Comment: @J.Doe , Gimp can be installed from the command line without adding the ppa , but you need to solve its dependencies , i proposed to add the `ppa` because it is the easy way.